# Bullets position in Chrome and IE

Tags: css

I am facing a problem with the position of bullets
It looks fine in Firefox but in Chrome and IE it gets messed up

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome/IE:

[image]

This is a css for the shown div

```
background: url("/images/divider_right_top.jpg") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
font-size: 12px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 20px;
```

Comment: Can you make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Why do you have `scroll` in the `background`?

Comment: Are you floating anything inside your li?

Comment: Place your code in the jsfiddle

Comment: dont know so much it a readymade template i m just editing

Comment: check it here here it is looking perfect
http://jsfiddle.net/P9QpW/

Comment: The fiddle looks fine to me in all three browsers. So there must be something in your real page that is not in the fiddle. Do you have a link?

Comment: no its on a local server

Comment: The problem lies not withing your shared code. You need to share the css for your list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set directly the UL in the css like this:

```
#yourdiv ul{ list-position:outside; /*(or inside as you need)*/ 
             padding:20px;}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the padding. Use margins.

`ul { margin: 1em 0; }`
`li { margin: 0 0 0 1.4em }`

Comment: i am using umbraco
so when i add these properties to his theme's css nothing would change
i even tried to check it with firebug but it didnt show the rules that i added to css

Answer (score 0):

Give CSS for the list element like this'

```
li
{
background: url(/images/divider_right_top.jpg) no-repeat left;
padding-left: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: @Mohsin Mustufa Add Like this for that list Element